# Stop Android from switching networks

Tags: wi-fi

We have four different WiFi networks in our home which we use for different things. What I'm doing and where I am in the house dictates the one I want to use.

Android always tries to automatically connect to the network with the strongest signal strength, which is not necessarily the one I want to use. It becomes very annoying to have to keep switching it back to the one that I want.

Is there a way to make Android stay connected to the wifi network I select, until I either change it or go out of range of that network?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't protect your wifi with a password, then its likely that your phone automatically scans for open wifi connection and connects to 'nearest'. However, this only happens if you are no longer connected to or out of range of your desired network. So

1. Disabling auto scan for open network may ensure that you only connect to the active one.
2. Once you are done with the other networks, always remember to press "forget" on the wifi option

On the other hand if you have a password, then obviously you have stored the password of all the connection and using the "forget" option would mean entering the password each time.

So it may be that the strength of your desired connection is too weak or lost and the phone decides to connect to the nearest one, in which case there is nothing you can do but to make sure you are connected to the "right" network.

Hope it helped...